# Enabling the action bar's home button

Tags: android

Pressing on the app's icon doesn't change the activity, but I'd like it to return to the app's `MainActivity`.

I've made my app's icon appear on the left of the action bar by doing the following:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();                                   
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);                                   
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

I'm assuming I should define some functionality in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` methods of the activities concerned. I've gotten a log of the MenuItem's ID when the app's icon is pressed and `onOptionsItemSelected()` gets called, but obviously I can't hardcode that id into the switch statement. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `android:parentActivityName` for your activity in the manifest file.

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
```

You also need to handle the click in `onOptionsItemSelected` for the id of `android.R.id.home`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

See more on [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

Comment: Thanks for that - this is more or less right. As the linked page demonstrates, you still need to handle the app icon press in the onOptionsItemSelected() method.

Comment: Thanks, I've added to the answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it

```
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.HomeButtonId){
                    //Return Home
                    }
               }
```